# Is there any part in India which was not part of British Raj?

Tags: india

If we consider the princely states as part of the British Raj, Is there any province, territory, area, or landmass in the Republic of India that was not part of the British Raj?

Comment: Are you asking about states which were not a part of British India?

Comment: typically everything older than say 20 years is better suited for the history stackexchange

Comment: should be moved to diferent SE comunity: https://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I haven't voted on this Q, but it would probably be better if it included an explanation how it is relevant to today's politics.

Comment: I think History requires a bit more research, please see [this post on their meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Firstly "British India" ≠ "British Raj". In British India, the local ruler was British. But there were also regions of India, the so-called "Princely states", that were ruled by local Kings, Princes, Maharajas. These local rulers in turn offered allegiance to the British.

The "Raj" was the entire region over which the British had ultimate control, and, roughly:
"Raj" = "British India" + "Princely states".

Then there were other colonial powers in South Asia.  Goa was Portuguese, Puducherry was French. These areas were never in the British Raj.

Finally there were regions in the Hindu Kush or in the Andaman and Nicobar islands, for example, in which, while there may have been a British claim, there was no de facto British authority. (Indeed, while these islands are Indian on the map, there are some which are peopled by "uncontacted" tribes.)

Comment: This is exactly what my question in the coment to the question was.